# Docker compose watch and web live reload

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I managed to be able to do dev watching directly with docker-compose and a Makefile.

```
FROM node:alpine as init
ADD package.json .
ADD package-lock.json .

FROM init as install
RUN npm install

FROM install AS build
ADD _javascript _javascript
ADD _sass _sass
ADD package.json .
ADD .babelrc .
RUN npm run deploy

FROM scratch as release
COPY --from=build /css /public
COPY --from=build /js /public
ADD index.html /public

FROM node:alpine as dev
RUN npm install --global http-server
EXPOSE 80
CMD http-server /public -p 80 -c-1
COPY --from=release /public /public
```

Docker compose file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  release:
    build:
      context: .
      target: release
    image: ${IMAGE_NAME?}:${IMAGE_TAG?}

  dev:
    build:
      context: .
      target: dev
    image: ${IMAGE_NAME?}/dev:${IMAGE_TAG?}
```

And then the Makefile using watchexec:

```
all: dev
    watchexec make dev

dev:
    docker-compose build dev
    docker-compose up --remove-orphans --detach dev
    docker-compose ps

clean:
    docker-compose down --remove-orphans
```

This is working very great and allows me to get a well refreshed running project at any moment when I edit a JS file, a CSS one or even the Dockerfile.

With docker cache building, only the needed part are done.

But I'm missing one thing: Static server with live-reloading and CSS inject if possible.

How would you achieve it this using docker watching like I did?

Comment: I wouldn’t use Docker, especially for a pure Web application.  The only host dependency you need is Node itself (which you probably already have), and everything else is encapsulated within the project’s `node_modules` directory.

Comment: I appreciate you comment, but it is not related to the question. I want to all build onto docker to ensure ISO from dev to production. Same method will be used across many project (not only node).

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve my problematic using livejs: http://livejs.com/

It regularly checks if changes are made on css, js or html content and update CSS or reload the page if necessary.

No complicated stuff, just include the script, and voilà !